# Did Paro have an older brother?

Tags: bo, plagues-makkos

The final plague struck down all the first-born males in Egypt.  Paro was not struck down this way, so does that mean he had an older brother?  If so, what happened to him that Paro, not the older brother, got the throne?  (Google led me to speculation that Paro was [Thutmose I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thutmose_I), but I don't see anything there about siblings and, anyway, we don't know if he's the right Paro.)

Or wouldn't Paro have been struck down anyway, because God had other plans for him?

Comment: Weren't all heads of households also struck? He certainly would have been the head of his household. I'm pretty sure I remember a Midrash that he was a first born, but that HaShem wanted him to witness the miracles and salvation, in any case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rashi ([12:32](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9873/showrashi/true)) says that Pharoah asked Moshe to bless him because he was a firstborn and thus was liable to die in the plague.

Answer (score 3):

The verse says "from the firstborn of Paro who sits on his throne to the firstborn of maid who is behind the millstones", thus implying that anyone greater than Paro's son, i.e. Paro himself, was exempt from the plague.