# Looking for Midrash which says Pharaoh was not a firstborn

Tags: midrash, yetziat-mitzrayim, shemot-exodus

I remember learning some time ago about Pharaoh during the time of Yetizias Mitzrayim not being a first born because he slayed all of his brothers to become king, but now I can't find it.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to find this midrash? I assume it's somewhere in Shemos Rabbah. Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25686/472

Answer (score 1):

The midrash Tanhuma [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=NcYtAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA3&ots=ZbqbmfJeMf&dq=%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9F&pg=RA5-PA52#v=onepage&q&f=false) relates that Pharaoh was a first-born [by birth] and therefore besought Moshe to leave immediately with the Jews.

Comment: Okay, not the midrash I was looking for but cool anyways.

Comment: Granted, the answer does not provide a source for the author's (existing?) citation, but I think the answer does "point [him] in the right direction" that the signs down memory lane may have been misplaced. The Sefer HaYashar (Jeru. 1987, pg. 251) also records Moshe telling Pharaoh he is a firstborn. Basically, a midrashic source (in the answer) indicating the opposite is sufficient "direction", I think, that the author may be misremembering unless he accepts (based on certainty) that there are midrashim chalukim. But if you insist... can OP decide? (Still unfamiliar how things work here.)